# Texmaker freezes after 'Hat' operation

Tags: errors, texmaker

The operation `^` (i.e. `e^x`) is not working properly. When I write `^` Texmaker sometimes stops working.

I am using a MacBook if this has any influence.

EDIT:

[image]

So now it froze. Can't do anything. Can't delete, can't mark the text and can't print the PDF.
I can 'Save as' to continue, but AFAIK that's it.

This is the document where it freezes sometimes when I use '^'. This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead [L]{}
\fancyhead [R] {}
\rfoot{page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of
\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\[
^
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have to ask: Are you using `$e^x$`?

Comment: If it isn't what Werner suggested, post explicit code an cite the explicit error message

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: There's no error message really. It doesn't only happen at $e^x$ but also any other times I'm using it. Sometimes it just doesn't print '^', and other times LaTeX freezes. (So no error messages).

Comment: tex is a deterministic program it just follows the instructions in the input file. If you want us to help you fix your input, you need to show your input example that does not work as you expect.

Comment: Is it possible to post pictures?

Comment: Please don't use `$$...$$` in LaTeX as well. Use `\[...\]` instead

Comment: what was the intention of `^^^^^^^^^^^^^^` it is is going to do nothing useful, or produce an error message, depending on whether there is a multiple of 3 `^` in the sequence but why would you have that in the input file?

Comment: do not post a picture post a small complete document, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that generates the error. You can use the `{}` button in the editor to mark it as a code section so line endings are preserved.

Comment: Right, so the reason I put it in the input file was to demonstrate (which I can see now did not go well) that after a few ^'s LaTeX freezes. It also happens after a single ^. This time I just tried to see how many ^'s I had to type in order to make it freeze.

Comment: @NikolaiBonnerup as I say it will depend on whether you have a multiple of three but why would you ever do that at all?  `^` is a command that starts a superscript. what do you want `^^^^^^^^^^^` to do other than generate an error?

Comment: So as I said it also happens after I just type it only 1 time.

Comment: did you type it in math mode? we only need to ask all these questions as you have provided no example... `^` is a math mode command to make a superscript, if you use it in text mode it generates an error.

Comment: It happens both in math mode and also when not in math mode.

Comment: the error messages  will be different but whether in math or not, a string of `^^^^` has no possible useful output.

Comment: I get that it wont be useful.
Here's my problem: Sometimes when I use '^', my LaTeX freezes.

Comment: if latex freezes then you have programmed an infinite loop into your document.  We can only correct that error if you show the code. as requested above a complete document in a code section (like the document in my current answer)

Comment: Compiling you example just spits out two error messages, because a lonely `^` in a formula is of course invalid.

Comment: The new document posted does not "freeze" (= go into an infinite loop) it simply gives an error message about the mis-use of `^`. What else would you expect it to do given that input?

Comment: I extended my answer to cover the math mode usage in the new example.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here about what is "Latex". I believe @NikolaiBonnerup is saying that his _editor_ sometimes freezes when he types the `^` character.

Comment: There is some text-editing wonkiness in Sierra (see, for example, https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7778906 ).  What program are you using?  (You don't seem to mention.)  Can you trigger the problem reliably by typing enough `^`s?  If so, how many?

Comment: I am using texmaker, and yeah it's the editor thats freezing. And yes I can trigger it kind of reliably. The amount of '^' I have to use is not consistent though.

Answer (score 13):

`^` is a math mode command for a superscript and `^^` is a general command (like the control key) to shift the character code of the following character by 64.

so in text mode with one `^`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

^

\end{document}
```

you get the error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.5 ^
```

with two `^^`

you get no error, and it typesets an M as end of line is control-M so shifting that by 64 gives M

with three `^^^`

you get the error

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.5 ^^^
```

as control-^ (character hex 1E, decimal 30) isn't set up as an input character.

Adding more `^` will just give multiple occurrences of these errors unless you stop at the first one.

---

As the example in the question has been changed I will repeat the above but with math mode.

In display math with one `^`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[ ^ \]


\end{document}
```

Produces the error

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   $
l.5 \[ ^ \]
```

As the end of display math is taken inside the superscript and TeX's grouping is messed up.

With two `^^` you get no error and a single ``` \`` typeset as ```^^ ` is control-space that is character 32+64=96 which is an open quote in TeX's default OT1 encoding.

With three `^^^` you get

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.5 \[ ^^^
```

as in text mode as control-^ is set as an invalid control character.

As in text mode if you add more than three `^` you just get repeats of this behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

`^` Is a character with many purposes in TeX systems. For the normal usages:

In order to use it to print an exponent you:

1. Have to be in math mode, i.e. be between `\(` and `\)` or `$` and `$` or `\[` and `\]` or in an environment like `equation`, etc.
2. Use it as you normally would.

In order to print a hat over your letter (like ê) you should use either:

- unicode input (using an utf8 native engine, like Lua/Xe(La)TeX or `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
- use:

  - in text mode `\^e`
  - in math mode `\hat{e}`

Single `^` characters are not valid during LaTeX inputs (normally) hence the errors.

**EDIT**

Examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\centering
\^e ê $ e^{x}$

\begin{equation}
\hat{a}=e^{x+1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

**Advanced stuff**

When `^` is followed by another `^` and:

- a character of code < 128

or

- two of the lowercase hexadecimal digits: `0123456789abcdef`

then the whole trio/quartet gets replaced by a single character. with the rules found in the TeX Book, chapter 8. (In the *millennium edition* is pages 46-7)

Comment: Don't forget the `^^+` usage in the input level processing ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think is a bit off topic, don't you think?

Comment: No, since you referred to 'with many purposes' ... ;-) It's a completion:-P

Comment: Why do you say `\^e` is not recommended (besides the recommended LaTeX syntax `\^{e}`)? With `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` `\^e` and `ê` is the same

Comment: @clemens I think that the second one selects the correct font from the font table, using then the kern tables from the font, while the first one manually positions the accent, without consulting the font kern tables. You can see the different results in the image above.

Comment: @clemens Well if you see the image above, obtained by the code I indicated, you'll see the position of the accent is different. I don't know why it is so, but the result is there to see: the second accent is lower and a bit more to the left

Comment: @Moriambar try `\^e\llap{ê}` and see if you still think there are visual differences :)